Matlab: bvp5c with inconsistent eigenvalues
I'm trying to solve an boundary value problem with eigenvalues, following the article ( https://doi.org/10.1063/5.0155331 )
equation
where α and At are certain numbers and Q(σ) is a known function, error function in this case.
ϕ is the unknown function and Ψ the eigenvalue.
The boundary condition was set as bc (sometimes the right spot needs to be varied)
Most of the times, my code works well and give a result similar to Fig.1 in https://doi.org/10.1063/5.0155331 . However, the asymptotic values are different from result in the paper.
Most importantly, when I change the initial guess of Psi1, the result differs dramatically.
For example, when I set the initial guess as 1, I can get an asymptotic value of 11, and I change the initial guess to 11, then the asymptotic value just becomes 13 or something larger.
On the other hand, if the change the initial guess to 0, I just get an asymptotic value of 8.5.
I quite don't know what is happening. Thanks for any suggestion or some alternative approach to this problem.
eigenvalues0 = zeros(1, 30);
global alpha;
global At;
options = bvpset('RelTol',1e-5,'AbsTol',1e-5);
At = 0;
for i=1:30    
alpha=1/i;
Psi1 = 1;
solinit = bvpinit(linspace(-3,6,30000),@mat4init,Psi1);
sol = bvp5c(@mat4ode, @mat4bc, solinit,options);
 eigenvalues0(1,i) = sol.parameters;
end
figure(Color="white");
plot(eigenvalues0);
grid on;
legend('0','0.243','0.5','0.843','0.999','FontSize', 14)
xlabel('\alpha^{-1}','FontSize', 14);
ylabel('\Psi','FontSize', 14);
set(gca, 'FontSize', 14);
function dydx = mat4ode(x,y,Psi1) % equation being solved
global alpha;
global At;
dydx = [y(2)
        (-alpha^2*At*2/sqrt(pi)*exp(-x.^2)*y(2)+(1+At*erf(x)-alpha*Psi1*2/sqrt(pi)*exp(-x.^2))*y(1))/(alpha^2*(1+At*erf(x)))];
end
function res = mat4bc(ya,yb,Psi1) % boundary conditions
global alpha;
res = [ya(2)-1/alpha*exp(-3/alpha)
       abs(yb(1))+abs(yb(2))
       %yb(2)
       ya(1)-exp(-3/alpha)];
end
function yinit = mat4init(x) % initial guess function
global alpha;
yinit = [exp(-abs(x)/alpha)
        -sign(x)*1/alpha*exp(-abs(x)/alpha)];
end

Actually I tried to address this problem with Mathematica(which I am further better at), however Mathematica always returns a linear solution of Psi and never with an asymptotic behavior.
